API Connect Gateway consuming a REST API with OAuth2 Implicit Grant flow
I need to use API Connect to consume a REST API that is protected using OAuth Implicit Grant flow. Hence I have to a) get an access token from the Authentication service endpoint, and b) use that access token to consume the REST API from the AI endpoint. My questions are:

Can API Connect support the OAuth Implicit Grant, in the role of a Client (in the OAuth sense)
If so, does API Connect manage the lifecycle of the token (if it expires, refresh it automatically) automatically, and how?

Thanks in advance
